# Fetch string in express API to pass into mongodb find function

Tags: mongodb, express, mean-stack, mean

I am working with express API js to connect with mongoDB. I am trying to pass parameter to the find function of mongodb, when i am passing it as a hardcoded value it fetches the data correctly but when i am passing a dynamic string value it doesn't accept. Please find below the code for clearer idea,

-----API.JS-----

```
router.get('/external_sources_details_filtered',(req,res) =>{
   connection((db) => {
   let parameterValue = String( 'frequency.'+ req.query.frequency);
        console.log(parameterValue);
        var query1 = {parameterValue :{$exists:true}};
        var query2 ={'frequency.Monthly':{$exists:true}};
        console.log(query1);
        console.log(query2);
        var projection = {_id:0,sourceID:1,SourceName:1, Outstanding:1};
         db.collection('external_sources').find(query2)
         .project(projection).toArray()
         .then((external_sources_details_filtered) => {
          response.data = external_sources_details_filtered;
         res.json(response);
    })
  })      
 })
```

Output of console.log(**query1**) = { parameterValue: { '$exists': true } }

Output of console.log(**query2**) = { 'frequency.Monthly': { '$exists': true } }

Why does parameterValue is not being fetched while passing it in query1 even after casting  parameterValue to string?

Comment: Because you're using parameterValue as the key of an object. If you  want to use the variable, you should try `{[parameterValue]: {$exists: true}}`. This is an ES6 feature, and you can read a little more about it [here](http://wtfruby.com/javascript/2017/01/04/js-dynamic-attr-names.html)

Comment: This worked...Thank you so much for your support @user184994

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: Because i was using parameterValue as the key of an object. If you want to use the variable, you should try {[parameterValue]: {$exists: true}}
. This is an ES6 feature, and you can read a little more about it here http://wtfruby.com/javascript/2017/01/04/js-dynamic-attr-names.html